# Error when trying out SPRING (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext)

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-framework-beans

I'm trying to run a Junit test on my Spring application, which is an example from the book 'Spring in Action'. I'm a newbie at this so I'm just getting started but I'm getting this error when I try to run the test class: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext**

Anyone knows what's going on?

Test Class:

```
import com.self.CDPlayerConfig;
import com.self.CompactDisc;
import com.self.SgtPeppers;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {
    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

CDPlayerConfig:

```
package com.self;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
C:\Users\polar\.jdks\openjdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53385:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\polar\Desktop\Programming Resources\MavenPracticeProject\target\test-classes;C:\Users\polar\Desktop\Programming Resources\MavenPracticeProject\target\classes;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.2\spring-core-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.2\spring-jcl-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.30.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.30.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.30.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.30.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.30.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.30.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.30.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.30.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.3.3\spring-test-5.3.3.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13.1\junit-4.13.1.jar;C:\Users\polar\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 CDPlayerTest
Jan 19, 2021 12:27:06 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3420)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2631)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.instantiateListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getTestExecutionListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:167)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 27 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same version for all Spring dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please update at least all components to version 5.3.3 or to the latest available version.

Spring is a project with multiple modules: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework and different versions of Spring components can throw many different exceptions like: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and etc.

Comment: Thanks! That works! I learnt something new too :)